# Exception of an indent block if it isn't needed? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently writing some code, nothing special, but then i got this while trying to fix indents.

```
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ttc2/main.py", line 67
return await asyncio.gather(*[self._check(sess, u) for u in self.to_check])
                                                        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'with' statement on line 66
```

Now, I'm confused where the indent is required, could anyone help?

Comment: After a line ending on `:` an indentation is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the code so we could help you, anywho

you should make an indentation after using with

```
with open(filename,mode) as w:
    w.write('hello')
```